# Magento2 - Failed Data validation at product import

Tags: magento2, import, products

I try to update all my Product-images with an import via `.csv`. I got all the images in `pub/media/import` and declared them in the `csv`-file.

Even everything should be valid i get a error:

```
Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.

Checked rows: 8832, checked entities: 9041, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 1
```

Since i cant find the error or it is not visible for me I cant resolve it...

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, M2's import/export errors are extremely cryptic. Can you post your CSV to a pastebin and then I'll try to run it and step through the code for you?

Comment: Unfortunately its to big for pastebin. I uploaded it there for you http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a03b94886588468d24dd55e5b701fc38/import.csv

Comment: Try to debug the core code to log the root error.

Comment: Once i try to import and wait for the error i checked the `var/logs` directory for the `debug.log` but nothing is in there.

Comment: @MarcelH. I'm not sure what's going on here. It won't import successfully for me because I don't have any of those products.

Comment: I have met the same problem. The source of the problem was the character encoding of the file. I opened the file in the correct character encoding using Sublime (in my example it was Turkish Windows 1254). Then I saved it in UTF-8 format. I did not get an error when I checked it again. I hope it helps anyone.